# Experiments with Podman-compose hanging

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I have a rather simple docker-compose file (One Mongo Service, one test service):

```
version: "3.7"                                                                  
  services:                                                                       
      mongo:                                                                      
        image: docker.io/mongo:4.4                                                
        container_name: mongo                                                     
        environment:                                                              
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root                                       
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example                                    
                                                                                  
      test:                                                                       
        build:                                                                    
          context: ./..                                                           
          dockerfile: ./tests/Dockerfile                                          
                                                                                 
        image: antarctic_test                                                     
                                                                                 
        volumes:                                                                  
          - ./../tests/:/project/tests:ro                                         
          - ./../xxx/:/project/xxx:ro                                           
                                                                                 
        depends_on:                                                               
          - mongo                                                                 
                                                                                 
        command: >                                                                
          poetry run pytest                                                       
          # should I kill mongo service explicitly here. If so, how?
```

As part of our CI/CD process I would like to run this with podman-compose.
This actually works(!) with

```
poetry run podman-compose run -d mongo
poetry run podman-compose run test
podman pod rm -f tests
```

But that's bad. I shouldn't be forced to start the mongo service explicitly before I enter the test service. It's also not how modern docker-compose works.
I think a better approach would be

```
poetry run podman-compose up test                                               
poetry run podman-compose down
```

However, in this case it executes the tests and then hangs forcing me to shutdown the mongo service with Ctrl C explicitly. This is somewhat disappointing. Even more so, as this construction works beautifully with docker-compose.

I guess the short answer could be that I shouldn't rely on podman-compose but I would like to understand better what's going on. Maybe I do something stupid in the docker-compose.yml. Please tell me